# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la inversa de un CRC8 sabiendo la trama completa?

Tags: python

Tras varios intentos calculando el CRC8 de unas tramas que poseo, no soy capaz de encontrar la manera original en la que se calcula.
Lo he intentado con la librería de Python "libscrc" calcularlo utilizando los CRC8 estandarizados que incluye, pero no hay ninguna coincidencia, también he insertado las tramas en varios calculadores online de CRC pero nada.

La idea es poder obtener el polinomio generador utilizado originalmente, teniendo en cuenta que a la entrada o salida, puede haberse realizado un XOR y haberle dado la vuelta al resultado.

Las tramas que tengo son la siguientes, con cabecera y CRC8 incluidos:

0x02 0x01 0x05 0x33 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

0x02 0x01 0x05 0x33 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x6f

0x02 0x01 0x05 0x33 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x0a

0x02 0x01 0x05 0x33 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0xb4

Estas tramas incluyen al final el CRC8 calculado, lo que deseo es saber cómo se ha calculado para que cuando yo envíe una trama, pueda calcular el CRC correcto.Necesito el algoritmo para generar dicho CRC8.

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente script se utiliza la librería mencionada para obtener los CRC, yo introduzco la trama sin el CRC sustituyendo dicha posición por 0X00.

Para encontrar el CRC deseado para la primera de las tramas añadidas, el resultado obtenido tras ejecutar el programa debería de ser 0X00 en alguno de los CRC8 obtenidos.

He probado el script quitando las cabezeras para ver si de alguna forma lo consigo pero no hay coincidencia.

```py
   import libscrc

code="020105330800000000"

#Transformar de hex a byte el código
code=bytes.fromhex(code)


#Calcular los crc8:
crc8 = libscrc.intel(code)
crc8=hex(crc8)
print("intel:      "+crc8)
crc8 = libscrc.bcc(code)
crc8=hex(crc8)
print("bcc:        "+crc8)
crc8 = libscrc.lrc(code)
crc8=hex(crc8)
print("lrc:        "+crc8)
crc8 = libscrc.maxim8(code)
crc8=hex(crc8)
print("maxim8:     "+crc8)
crc8 = libscrc.rohc(code)
crc8=hex(crc8)
print("rohc:       "+crc8)
crc8 = libscrc.itu8(code)
crc8=hex(crc8)
print("itu8:       "+crc8)
```

PD:La librería tiene más CRC8 pero no los añado aquí.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues tu código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Cómo se calcula el CRC8? ¿Cual es la entrada, la salida obtenida y el resultado esperado? ¿Cual es el código que usas?